# Does CSP apply to React Native?

Tags: react-native, content-security-policy

Does Content Security Policy apply to React Native?

It looks like JavaScript is still processed at runtime.

UPDATED:

Would CSP header make a React Native application more secure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Apply CSP by configuring the `Content-Security-Policy` header in your app's HTTP response, an example can [be found here](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-content-security-policy-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/).

Note that CSP is only enforced by modern web browsers and may not be supported by all browsers or platforms.

Comment: Could you elaborate why CSP applies to React Native?

Comment: cause it's a JS framework for building mobile apps. react uses javascript, right?  https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment

Comment: @KevinC React Native would be like a web browser in that it can make HTTP requests and do something with the responses, but it is *not* a web browser. So it is not clear to me that CSP applies to React Native.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, **Content Security Policy (CSP)** can be applied to React Native applications. CSP is a security feature that helps prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) and other code injection attacks by specifying which sources of content are allowed to be loaded by a web page or application. React Native applications, like other web applications, can benefit from the use of CSP to help prevent security vulnerabilities.

Implementing CSP in a React Native application typically involves adding a "Content-Security-Policy" header to HTTP responses served by the server. The header value specifies the policy for the application, including which sources of content are allowed to be loaded. In React Native, you can add the header by configuring the server that serves the application, or by using a third-party library such as react-native-csp.

Comment: Could you provide a link to react-native-csp?

Comment: I can't find a package called `react-native-csp`. @isobretatel it looks like CSP is irrelevant to a React Native app

Comment: The package `react-native-csp` does not exist.